# Abrupt IO speed decrease in a multithreaded Python script on GCP

Tags: python, multithreading, image-processing, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I'm running a Python script that loads images, preprocesses the images in some way, and saves the image back to a cache directory. There's about 500k images. It was taking too long to run for our use case, so I added multithreading. We're running on a GCP Compute Engine VM instance with the raw images located on a HDD, and the preprocessed images being saved to SSD.

When using 8 vCPU's and 12 threads, it does around 30-40 images per second for the first 30 seconds or so. Awesome speed and totally works for our use case. Then after 30 seconds, it suddenly drops down to around 1 image per second, which is not acceptable. The slowdown happens essentially instantaneously and remains at a consistent 1 image per second over the course of hours. I need to reboot the instance to achieve higher speeds again, although it always slows down. Restarting the Python script still results in 1 image per second from the beginning.

It does a similar thing when I limited the max number of threads to 4 and even 1 thread. In the single worker case, it ran for about 3 minutes at 5 images per second before it slowed down to 1 image per second. So it seems to be some type of rate limiting / resource exhaustion / quota limit.

What could be causing this problem? And how can I resolve the problem?

Here's a code sample showing usage:

```
import concurrent
import io
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(...)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=12) as pool:

    pool.map(preprocess_row,
             df['raw_path'],
             df['cache_path'],
             chunksize=1)
    )


def preprocess_row(raw_path, cache_path):
    
    img = io.imread(raw_path)
    img = ...                  # Arbitrary preprocessing

    io.imsave(cache_path, img)
```

Using ProcessPoolExecutor resulted in the same slowdown to 1 image per second:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as pool:
    ...
```

Comment: I don't believe threading is the appropriate tool as this is not an IO problem. Have you experimented with multiprocessing.pool instead?

Comment: I have not yet. I timed the different steps and it appeared to be IO bound due to read/write of images. I'll still give multiprocessing.pool a shot, thanks!

Comment: Used ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) and still am seeing roughly equivalent initial speeds, followed by 1 image per second

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Google's compute thing works. I see this sort of slowdown when a program runs out of RAM, so I agree with your conclusion that it's a resource exhaustion issue. If there's a way you can monitor memory usage, then that'd be the place to start. You mention saving to the cache directory. I'm not entirely certain what that means, but cache memory is typically pretty small (at the tradeoff of being very fast) and it wouldn't take too many images to fill it up.

Comment: I installed a monitoring tool to check memory use, and it only reached 4.5% of memory. I use the term cache directory informally. It's on a 1TB persistent SSD so no chance of running out of storage space based on our dataset size.